# WP_Query loop else statement not executing

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have two `WP_query` loops in my frontpage.php file:

```
<div id="aanbod">
<div class="container-fluid section-name-cont">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 section-name"><h1>Aanbod</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'         => 'vastgoedobject',
        'meta_key'          => 'status', 
        'meta_value'        => array('Te Huur', 'Binnenkort te huur'),
        'posts_per_page'    =>-1,
    );
    $aanbod_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $aanbod_query->have_posts() ) : $aanbod_query->the_post(); 
?>

  <div class="content-section-<?php if( $the_query->current_post%2 == 1 ){ echo 'b';}else{ echo 'a';} ?>">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 <?php if( $the_query->current_post%2 == 1 ){ echo 'col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-push-6 ';} ?>col-sm-6 lead-parent">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2 class="section-heading"><?php the_field('straat'); ?> <?php the_field('huisnummer'); ?>, <?php the_field('stad'); ?></h2></a>
            <span class="label label-default"><?php the_field('status'); ?></span>
            <span class="label label-default"><?php echo $euro ;?><?php the_field('totale_huurprijs'); ?>,-</span>
            <span class="label label-default"><?php the_field('verdieping'); ?></span>
            <span class="label label-default"><?php the_field('aantal_kamers'); ?>-kamer <?php the_field('beschrijving_vastgoed'); ?></span>
            <span class="label label-default"><?php the_field('totaaloppervlak'); ?> <?php echo $m2 ;?></span>
            <?php the_field('beschrijving'); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Bekijk <?php the_field('beschrijving_vastgoed'); ?></button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 <?php if( $the_query->current_post%2 == 1 ){ echo 'col-sm-pull-6';}else{ echo 'col-lg-offset-2';} ?> col-sm-6">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="foto-wrapper">
                <?php if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) {
                echo get_image_object_acf('img-responsive img-rounded', 'false', 'foto', '', 'fp-aanbod', 'glyphicon-share-alt');
                } else {
                echo get_image_object_acf('img-responsive img-rounded', 'false', 'foto', '', 'fp-aanbod', '');
                } ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<h1>Kampbeheer heeft momenteel niks te huur!</h1>

<?php 
    endif; 
    rewind_posts(); 
?>
```

```
<div id="onlangs-verhuurd">
<div class="container-fluid section-name-cont">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 section-name"><h1>Onlangs Verhuurd</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
  $args = array( 
    'post_type'         => 'vastgoedobject',
    'meta_key'          => 'status', 
    'meta_value'        => array('Verhuurd'),
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    );
  $verhuurd_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $verhuurd_query->have_posts() ) : $verhuurd_query->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="content-section-<?php if( $the_query->current_post%2 == 0 ){ echo 'b';}else{ echo 'a';} ?>">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 <?php if( $the_query->current_post%2 == 0 ){ echo 'col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-push-6 ';} ?>col-sm-6 lead-parent">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h2 class="section-heading"><?php the_field('straat'); ?>, <?php the_field('stad'); ?></h2>
            <?php if(get_field('totaaloppervlak')) { ?><span class="label label-default"><?php the_field('totaaloppervlak'); ?> <?php echo $m2 ;?></span><?php } ?>
            <?php the_field('beschrijving'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 <?php if( $the_query->current_post%2 == 0 ){ echo 'col-sm-pull-6';}else{ echo 'col-lg-offset-2';} ?> col-sm-6 foto-wrapper">
            <?php echo get_image_object_acf('img-responsive img-rounded', 'false', 'foto', '', 'fp-aanbod', '') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>Niks te weergeven hier!</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The `<?php endwhile; else: ?>` part is not working, it is just displaying nothing instead of `<h1>Kampbeheer heeft momenteel niks te huur!</h1>` or `<p>Niks te weergeven hier!</p>` when no posts are queried

What am I missing here?

Comment: `rewind_posts()` should be `wp_reset_postdata()`. Remember to add this to both queries just after ``endwhile`. Also, your `if` statements shoul also be set to your query variable, not just you `while()` statement and `the_post()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() )
```

To

```
<?php if ( $verhuurd_query->have_posts() )
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `have_posts` is for the main loop, so the `if` statement is checking the main loop,  which will probably always have posts. You want to use the custom query's `have_posts` for the `if` statement instead.

```
if ( $verhuurd_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $verhuurd_query->have_posts() ) : $verhuurd_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Manny! that's a concise clear answer! will keep that in mind